# MySQL ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE and CONCAT

Tags: mysql, on-duplicate-key

I have a query (`Code` is the `PRIMARY KEY`):

```
INSERT INTO table (Code, ... events)
  VALUES
    (1, ... CONCAT(events, 'BAR')),
    (2, ... CONCAT(events, 'BAR')),
    ...
  ON DUPLICATE KEY
    UPDATE ... events = VALUES(events)
```

My intention is that the `events` value being inserted is concatenated to the existing value if there's already a row for the given key.

With my query, assuming the existing value of `events` is `FOO`, the new `events` values are always `'BAR'` instead of `'FOOBAR'`.

What is the correct way to achieve what I want?

Comment: `events = VALUES(events)` where do you concatenate the old value?

Comment: CONCAT(events, '\nEDIT') events will return null at this point so insert will be null to events.

Comment: Maybe you can use GROUP_CONCAT() function

Comment: Please post your wished output

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To concatenate the new value to the old, move the `CONCAT` call into the `UPDATE`:

```
INSERT INTO table (Code, ... events)
  VALUES
    (1, ... 'BAR'), -- insert plain values
    (2, ... 'BAR'),
    ...
  ON DUPLICATE KEY
    UPDATE ... events = CONCAT(IFNULL(events, ''), VALUES(events)) -- concat if key same
```

One note about using `IFNULL()`. If your column `events` allows `NULL` values, it happens that result after update will be `NULL` again if existing value is `NULL` already. To prevent this, we *initialize* value by using `IFNULL(events, '')` before appending your additional data.